# Table view showing duplicate values

Tags: iphone

Table view showing duplicate values. It calls

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *) cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { }
```

method two times. Why is it happening? Actually table view showing array values.

Comment: How many sections do you have? Maybe this is the issue (e.g. having 2 sections and thus calling the method once for each section)

Comment: have you check your table array value? if not then please NSLog your array first.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSSet method to avoid duplicate values.  NSArray instead of NSMutableArray. You could use

```
   [values setArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:values] allObjects]];
```

or

```
 NSMutableArray* uniqueValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
 for(id e in Values)
 {
    if(![uniqueValues containsObject:e])
    {
       [uniqueValues addObject:e];
    }
}
```